# Toggle visibility of a complex popover-style css menu with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle

I am trying to implement an iOS popover-style menu for a mobile layout [based on this proof of concept](https://forrst.com/posts/CSS3_iPad_style_popover_menu-PJv).

I have tried solutions given on previous answers on this forum, and have narrowed down the toggle function to the simplest 2-line code. This renders the menu items correctly on my page, check out the demo & live code:

http://jsfiddle.net/vgbn/eU2Zc/

However, I wasn't able to toggle the visibility with the JS code, and I was wondering whether it's the JS or the CSS that prevents the show/hide div?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change yout function to **return false;**

```
$(function(){
$(".popmenu").click(function() {

    $(".popover").toggle();
  return false;
});
});
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsbin.com/ixuvax/1/edit)